# NSDateFormatter fails to return a datetime for UK region with 12 hour clock set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

This code works for every region/locale combination I can determine EXCEPT if I set my phone to UK region with the 12 hour clock set. Can anyone tell me why?

This works for every region including the UK with 12 hour clock set:

```
NSDateFormatter *theDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
theDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ";

NSString *theLastFetchDateString = @"2015-11-13T01:47:52.4630000Z";
NSDate *theLastFetchDate = [theDateFormatter dateFromString:theLastFetchDateString];
```

This works in every region EXCEPT the UK with the 12 hour clock set:

```
NSDateFormatter *theDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
theDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ";

NSString *theLastFetchDateString = @"2015-11-13T18:14:44.1230000Z";
NSDate *theLastFetchDate = [theDateFormatter dateFromString:theLastFetchDateString];
```

In the second case, theLastFetchDate is always nil.

The main difference I see is the second date is stored in 24 hour format where the parsing device is in 12 hour format, but the formatter HH should be able to handle that, yeah?

The other weird thing, and it is probably just a display thing, is the UK 12 hour clock formats times with 'a.m.' or 'p.m.' where the US 12 hour clock formats them as 'AM' or 'PM'.

Answer (score 6):

You are parsing a RFC 3339/ISO 8601 date. As such, you should set the `locale` of the formatter to be `en_US_POSIX`.

```
theDateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

See [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Still I am facing this issue , even though I have added Locale for "en_US_POSIX". Can you please help me?

Comment: @KeyurTailor - Please share example input date string and the `dateFormat` string that you are using.

Comment: Hi @Rob  I want "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", which is 24 hrs dateformat, but as i m having 12 hrs date format setting in my phone, the date which i am getting is always 12 hrs format, while i m checking with UK region

Comment: No, we literally want to see a self contained, [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem, showing us the input, the code used to produce the output, and the actual output. Nine times out of ten, the problem is some innocuous little issue. By the way, do you _really_ want that string without the typical `T` In the middle and without the `Z` at the end? What are you using this string for? Without the timezone specifier, it will assume local timezone, which generally introduces all sorts of issues, itself. I think you’re going to need to post your own question.

Comment: Hi @Rob I have asked the question with my sample code.